# Php site root url

Tags: php, paypal, payment-processing

I am doing a payment by paypal using submit the item details to paypal.
Here I need to specify a link of my notify.php.
For this I need to get my site root dynamically.
how can I get it.

my system folder structure is
     C:\wamp\www\website\store_esp\notify.php

and my url for notify.php should be
     http://domainname/store_esp/notify.php

Presently my domail name is http://localhost/website/

How can I get the domainname dynamically using php.

Comment: domain name is `localhost`. but website is just a catalog. go figure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` will give the domain name

```
 http://localhost/website
```

In the above URL the domain is `localhost` 
As I think the `website` is never changed to `website1` or `website2` so you can statically mention this in your url.

Comment: I have tried this
http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/store_esp/notify.php?status=T

But its giving 
http://localhost/store_esp/notify.php?status=F

But I need
http://localhost/website/store_esp/notify.php?status=F

Comment: . Your previous answer was right.. I need to use $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']. When it will be on live it would be ok.
So please revert your answer. Actually 2nd 1 is like doing anything force fully. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 4):

use this

```
http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/store_esp/
```

and after this use the filename like notify.php

Answer (score 0):

This PHP function returns the real URL of a full path.

```
function pathUrl($dir = __DIR__){

    $root = "";
    $dir = str_replace('\\', '/', realpath($dir));

    //HTTPS or HTTP
    $root .= !empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'https' : 'http';

    //HOST
    $root .= '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

    //ALIAS
    if(!empty($_SERVER['CONTEXT_PREFIX'])) {
        $root .= $_SERVER['CONTEXT_PREFIX'];
        $root .= substr($dir, strlen($_SERVER[ 'CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT' ]));
    } else {
        $root .= substr($dir, strlen($_SERVER[ 'DOCUMENT_ROOT' ]));
    }

    $root .= '/';

    return $root;
}
```

Call of pathUrl in this file : http://example.com/shop/index.php

```
#index.php

echo pathUrl();
//http://example.com/shop/
```

Work with alias : http://example.com/alias-name/shop/index.php

```
#index.php

echo pathUrl();
//http://example.com/alias-name/shop/
```

For sub directory : http://example.com/alias-name/shop/inc/config.php

```
#config.php

echo pathUrl(__DIR__ . '/../');
//http://example.com/alias-name/shop/
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36101073/3626097