# How do I get the root url of the site?

Tags: php

Might be a trivial question, but I am looking for a way to say get the root of a site url, for example: `http://localhost/some/folder/containing/something/here/or/there` should return `http://localhost/`

I know there is `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` but that's not what I want.

I am sure this is easy, but I have been reading: [This post](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) trying to figure out what i should use or call.

Ideas?

The other question I have, which is in relation to this one is - will what ever the answer be, work on sites like `http://subsite.localhost/some/folder/containing/something/here/or/there` so my end result is `http://subsite.localhost/`

Comment: Look at [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

Comment: if you have a single entry point for your site and/or you always include a config file you can use [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23864090/1815624).

Answer (score 63, accepted):

```
$root = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'https' : 'http') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/';
```

If you're interested in the current script's scheme and host. Depending on web server configuration (reverse proxy, rewrites), what is "current" may not be what you see in the browser, but it is what PHP thinks it is dealing with.

Otherwise, if you have a URL at hand you want the root of, parse_url(), as already suggested. e.g.

```
$parsedUrl = parse_url('http://localhost/some/folder/containing/something/here/or/there');
$root = $parsedUrl['scheme'] . '://' . $parsedUrl['host'] . '/';
```

If you're also interested in other URL components prior to the path (e.g. credentials), you could also use substr() on the full URL, with the start of the "path" as the stop position, e.g.

```
$url = 'http://user:pass@localhost:80/some/folder/containing/something/here/or/there';

$parsedUrl = parse_url($url);
$root = substr($url, 0, strpos($url, $parsedUrl['path'], strlen($parsedUrl['scheme'] . '://'))) . '/';//gives 'http://user:pass@localhost:80/'
```

Note: The offset in strpos() is used to handle the case where the URL might already be the root.

Comment: I'm reading `parse_url()` and I am not understanding how I would set it up, to give me what I want. Any ideas? sorry. but thanks for your help.

Comment: @Adam I've altered the answer above with an example for parse_url().
It's simple really - it gives you an associative array with all URL components, and you pick those you want. In your case, scheme and host.

Comment: @boen_robot: good work, but don't leave out stuff like the username, portnumbers, etc. that may be in there, look [here for instance](https://github.com/akky/anti-hatena-bookmark/blob/master/http_build_url.php#L106)

Comment: @Wrikken Well, it didn't seem like Adam wants that in particular, but I guess for the sake of others reading... I've modified the answer above to also include an example that would cover the scenarios you're talking about.

Comment: That information makes sense, yet I have one last question, if i have sub domains, such as `bla.localhost/site/content/here` and I use the above answer - will I get `bla.localhost/` back? or will I get.

Comment: @Adam Yes, you'll get the subdomain too. The full hostname in fact. If you're interested in individual portions of the host, do explode('.', $parsedUrl['host']), and inspect the resulting array (where each member is from the deepest subdomain up to the TLD).

Comment: @boen_robot Sorry I meant with $`root  = ... ` example

Comment: @Adam Right. In all examples above, the hostname will include subdomains too, so ```http://bla.localhost/site/content/here``` will give you ```http://bla.localhost/``` with all examples.

Comment: those who get the error `Undefined index: HTTPS` please do as in the following link [click me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17218926/how-to-get-rid-of-php-notice-undefined-index-https-in-x-on-line-123)

Comment: @gvgvgvijayan I hadn't tested that first piece of code, so thanks... I've corrected the code above to use "!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])", which AFAIK should remove this notice, since an isset() is implicitly done.

Comment: beware: the examples give you wrong paths with activated `php mod_rewrite` rules

Answer (score 17):

Another simple way:

```
<?php
$hostname = getenv('HTTP_HOST');
echo $hostname;
```

[**getenv**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php)

(PHP 4, PHP 5)

getenv — Gets the value of an environment variable

Comment: Nice and small however it doesn't include the `http` bit

Answer (score 14):

This PHP function returns the real URL of a full path.

```
function pathUrl($dir = __DIR__){

    $root = "";
    $dir = str_replace('\\', '/', realpath($dir));

    //HTTPS or HTTP
    $root .= !empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'https' : 'http';

    //HOST
    $root .= '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

    //ALIAS
    if(!empty($_SERVER['CONTEXT_PREFIX'])) {
        $root .= $_SERVER['CONTEXT_PREFIX'];
        $root .= substr($dir, strlen($_SERVER[ 'CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT' ]));
    } else {
        $root .= substr($dir, strlen($_SERVER[ 'DOCUMENT_ROOT' ]));
    }

    $root .= '/';

    return $root;
}
```

Call of pathUrl in this file : http://example.com/shop/index.php

```
#index.php

echo pathUrl();
//http://example.com/shop/
```

Work with alias : http://example.com/alias-name/shop/index.php

```
#index.php

echo pathUrl();
//http://example.com/alias-name/shop/
```

For sub directory : http://example.com/alias-name/shop/inc/config.php

```
#config.php

echo pathUrl(__DIR__ . '/../');
//http://example.com/alias-name/shop/
```

Comment: I removed your links to localhost, other people who are visiting the internet on different computers do not have access to your localhost box.  Also your other link to /myweb.com/tests/ does not resolve.

Answer (score 4):

You can using `Define` save on `define.php` include for next time use on other project
This is `PROTOCOL` `DOMAIN` `PORT` `SITE_ROOT` AND `SITE PATH`

```
**
 * domain
 * ex: localhost, maskphp.com, demo.maskphp.com,...
 */
define('DOMAIN', isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);

/**
 * protocol
 * ex: http, https,...
 */
define('PROTOCOL', isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 1)
    || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] === 'https' ? 'https' : 'http');

/**
 * port
 * ex: 80, 8080,...
 */
define('PORT', $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']);

/**
 * site path
 * ex: http://localhost/maskphp/ -> /maskphp/
 */
define('SITE_PATH', preg_replace('/index.php$/i', '', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));

/**
 * site root
 * ex: http://maskgroup.com, http://localhost/maskphp/,...
 */
define('SITE_ROOT', PROTOCOL . '://' . DOMAIN . (PORT === '80' ? '' : ':' . PORT) . SITE_PATH);
```

You can debug to see result

Answer (score 1):

You can `preg_split` the URL at the first single `/`-character:

```
function rootUrl($url) {
  $urlParts = preg_split('#(?<!/)/(?!/)#', $url, 2);
  return $urlParts[0] != '' ? $urlParts[0] . '/' : '';
}

// examples:

echo rootUrl('http://user@www.example.com/path/to/file?query=string');
// output: http://user@www.example.com/

echo rootUrl('https://www.example.com/');
// output: https://www.example.com/

echo rootUrl('https://www.example.com');
// output: https://www.example.com/

echo rootUrl('example.com/path/to/file');
// output: example.com/

echo rootUrl('/path/to/file');
// output: [empty]

echo rootUrl('');
// output: [empty]
```

The function `rootUrl($url)` returns the part of the given string `$url` before the first `/`-character plus a trailing `/` if that first part is not empty. For URLs starting with a `/` (relative URLs) an empty string is returned.