# Php path problems

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, path

I have a php file containing my navbar(menu.php) which is used from many of my pages.
Let me show you my folder structure:

index.php

```
html
   menu.php
   apps
       app1.php
       app2.php
   webdesign
       html.php
       js.php
```

and the following code:
  <

```
div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top navbar-topic">
            <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header"><!--navbar start-->
                <a  href="http://kounj.web44.net"  class="navbar-brand"><!--Logo -->
                    iloveprogramming
                </a>
                <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span><!--4 icon-bar spans create the dropdown menu-->
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>

                </button>
            </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Web Design <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="/webdesign/html.php">Html</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/webdesign/css.php">Css</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/webdesign/js.php">Javascript</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/webdesign/php.php">PHP</a></li>

                        </ul>


                        </li>
                        <li><a href="/apps/index.php">Tools</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!--navbar end-->
```

The problem is that when i use index.php which is on the root folder my links on navbar will not be set correctly.Any ideas

Comment: are you using any localserver?

Comment: your links should be from your root directory and not from the current file location

Comment: Where does your server's document root point?

Comment: Check this answer to get an Url from a path http://stackoverflow.com/a/36101073/3626097

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use absolute path by setting a constant in menu.php that might look like this:

```
define("ROOTPATH", "/var/www/html/apps/");
```

(A quick and dirty approach, but effective) for your Navigation links and setting them like so:

```
<a href="<?php echo ROOTPATH; ?>/app1.php</a>
<!-- etc -->
```

Or you can edit you [Apache http.conf](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-find-unix-linux-apache-documentroot/) file thereby pointing it to your PHP projects root folder, and restart apache to get your changes to take effect. But both will address your PHP file path issues.